# How can I convert this arrow function to a standard function?

Tags: javascript, function

I have an arrow function, offered graciously by [Ele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715121/ele) of the community here, but for the life of me, I can't understand it:

```
let isValid = function (arr, arr2) {
    let sum = (array, n) => array.reduce((a, an) => a + (an === n), 0);  
     return !arr2.some(n => !arr.some(an => an === n && sum(arr, an) === sum(arr2, n)))
};
```

Would someone be so kind as to translate this into a standard function so that I can follow it on my skill level?

Thank you.

My assumption:

```
function isValid (arr, arr2) {
    ...this is where i'm lost
}
```

Comment: Replace `(arr, arr2) =>` with `function (arr, arr2)`.  Repeat the same pattern.

Comment: Wait, I'm the creator of this.

Comment: Indeed, you are! I thank you again for this and I'm embarrassed to say your skill far outranks my own. I just need a more standard translation so that I can learn from it and expand my abilities so one day I can be as concise in my coding as you are.

Comment: `let sum = (array, n) => array.reduce...` can be written as `function sum(array, n) {return array.reduce...} `

Comment: You may want to read up on what callback functions are. The arrow syntax is a shorthand for those, but has some minor differences. Named functions are far easier to read however.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek no, a translation is what I'm asking for. I know what the code is doing, but not how it is doing it. The translation will help me decifer the method and learn how to code so concisely

Comment: The first arrow in the first snippet makes the syntax invalid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption is correct for the outer function. The first line inside it would become:

```
function sum(array, n) {
    return array.reduce(function(a, an) {
        return a + (an === n);
    }, 0);
```

[Have a read about Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and how they differ from conventional function declarations. Mostly (but not completely), they're just syntactical sugar vs. conventional functions.

They differ most markedly in terms of context, i.e. what `this` points to inside the function body. Arrow functions always run in the outer, prevailing context in which the function was declared. Conventional functions, e.g. via `bind()`, can be repointed to a different context.

```
let foo = function() {
    let bar = () => this;
    return bar();
}.bind('a');
foo(); //'a', because foo()'s context is 'a'
```

So how about that sugar? It can look confusing at first, especially when you have multiple arrow functions in one line. One key thing to remember is that they're just implicit shorthand for things you used to have to code manually.

```
let foo = a => a+1;
```

Is the same as

```
function foo2(a) { return a + 1; }
```

(The [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) will be different, but that's a bit beyond the scope of this answer.)

One thing we can tell from the above is there is that, where the part after `=>` is a single statement, it's interpreted as a return value, without us having to actually write `return`.

```
foo(1); //2
```

This is great for simple functions that do one job expressable in one line of code. If you need more verbose functions you enclose the code in `{}` as  usual.

```
let foo3 = a => {
    return a+1;
};
```

This again works identically to the `foo` and `foo2` above.

And so, finally, breaking down that fearsome line:

```
    let sum = (array, n) => array.reduce((a, an) => a + (an === n), 0);
```

It says:

- assign a function to the local scope variable `sum`
- it accepts two arguments, `array` and `n`
- it has one job to do, expressable as one line of code and so no need for binding `{` and `}` for the function body. That job is to call `reduce()` and return (implicitly) the value
- The first argument to `reduce`, the callback, accepts two arguemnts, `a` and `an`
- This callback, like the one to `reduce`, also has just one job to do, and that job is to return the value of `a + (an === n)`

One final word on the sugar, which you may have spotted above, is that, with arrow functions, if only a single argument is accepted you don't need to wrap it in brackets. Multiple arguments are, though, and comma-separated as usual.

```
let foo = single_arg => alert(1);
let foo2 = (arg1, arg2) => alert(2);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can use https://babeljs.io/ to compile from this new javscript to "old" javascript. You can try it directly on its home page.

Here's the output it gives:

```
var isValid = function isValid(arr, arr2) {
  var sum = function sum(array, n) {
    return array.reduce(function (a, an) {
      return a + (an === n);
    }, 0);
  };

  return !arr2.some(function (n) {
    return !arr.some(function (an) {
      return an === n && sum(arr, an) === sum(arr2, n);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: PS: you have to delete the `function` keyword from `let isValid = function (arr, arr2)` to compile correctly.

Answer (score 4):

That approach uses a lot of arrow functions, and can be translated to the following standard function declarations:

```
let isValid = function(arr, arr2) {
  let sum = function (array, n) {
    return array.reduce(function(a, an) {
      return a + (an === n); // coercion -> true = 1, false = 0
    }, 0);
  };

  return !arr2.some(function(n) {
    let sum2 = sum(arr2, n);
    return !arr.some(function(an) { 
      return an === n && sum(arr, an) === sum2;
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: so my followup question is, if arr and arr2 are user provided arrays, then where are n, a, an coming from? what do they equate to?

Comment: @Sweepster `n` from `arr2`, `a` is the accumulator of the function `reduce` and `an` is the current `name` of the loop from the function `reduce`.

Comment: @Sweepster I translated the arrow functions with the minor performance change.